# Pre-populate the internal storage in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-internal-storage

I'm making a quiz app that has the same screen for all the questions.
I want to store all the questions in a `ROOM database` and then load them one by one as the user progresses with levels.
The problem is the questions can be a `String` but sometimes can be an `image` (like who is in the picture?) and from my research I learned that using `typeConverters` to store image in `ROOM` is bad instead I should store them in the **internal storage** and then store the path of the image in `ROOM`.
Because it is a quiz app I have to prepopulate the `ROOM DB` so the app comes with all the questions ready which means the images should be pre-stored in `internal storage` and I can't seem to find a way to do that.
Is there any way i can do it? If not then what other way I can acheive this with?
**keep in mind that I plan to have an option in the future to load new questions from an API if the user want to!**

Answer (score 0):

If the answers come with the app, they should be prepackaged **resources** or **assets**, not files in internal storage. You can't prepackage into internal storage--that doesn't make sense because internal storage is part of the end-user's device. Read about how to use resources and assets [here in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).

Your table can have a column to indicate the image location (internal files you have downloaded or pre-packaged resources/assets) and the app can use that info to determine how to load the image.